# What to do when RadioButtonList selectedindexchanged event does not fire in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list that contains 2 items right now.Here is the aspx code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                     Height="52px" Width="181px" AutoPostBack="True" EnableTheming="True"
                     EnableViewState="true" onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Head of family "></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Show all">All Family Members</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

On page load when the page is loaded for the first time,I have set the first radio button item as the selected item through the following code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {                
            RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected = true;              
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ce)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + ce.Message + "');", true);
    }         
}
```

But after all of this, the selectedindexchanged event does not fire.I tried setting the EnableViewState property to true for the radiobuttonlist as well as for the page.I also tried setting the first item as selected through the aspx code rather than doing it at page load, but nothing worked.What should be done?This is the selectedindexchanged event:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

The first item gets selected, there are no issues, but when I try to select the second element, nothing happens apart from a postback.
There seems to be an issue with the radio buttons.I tried adding two radio buttons to the page to see if they work or not.Even simple radio buttons are not responding to selections.However when I add checkboxes, they work alright.

Comment: where is event `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged` ?

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar currently I have just kept the selectedindexchanged event blank.I will add it to my question if you wish to see it.

Comment: Doesn't it default to the first one in the list being selected?

Comment: Are you trying to fire selectedindexchange on load event? If yes then do `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(this, new EventArgs())` after `RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected = true;`

Comment: No @Avijit, I am just setting the first element as selected in the page load event.There are no problems there, but when I try to select the second item, no event fires, only a postback happens.

Comment: put a break point at RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged and try to click the other radio button, see what happen.

Comment: @Avijit, I have already tried that mate, the event doesn't fire.

Comment: Try like this as well. Remove `OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged"` from .aspx and add this in `Page_Load` `if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged += RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged;
            }`

Comment: Still not working @Avijit.

Answer (score 2):

If you select the item in the code behind, the event doesn't fire.

From MSDN:

> The SelectedIndexChanged event is raised when the selection from the list control changes between posts to the server.

More informations here:

[ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: See, the first item gets selected, there are no issues, but when I try to select the second element, nothing happens apart from a postback.

Comment: @TVicky what do you expect? You have no code inside `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged`. Sorry, but you need to be very clear when you post here.

Comment: I wanted to see the second element selected when I check the second element, but first of all, I just want the selectedindexchanged event to fire, which is not happening right now.

Comment: @TVicky the event fires only if click on the element on the page! is that clear? I've tried your code and it's fine!

Comment: I understand that very well Sir, and I have tried clicking the element already.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged"` from `RadioButtonList` control and try adding

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

in `Page_Load` *outside of*

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{                

}
```

block. See if that works.

Comment: This is weird, do you have other controls on the aspx page or additional code on cs file or is it as it appears here? Normally specifying onselectedindexchanged and setting autopostback property to true should be enough.